# what is the difference between process(sp) and process(shared_ptr<int>(sp))?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

```
void process(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr) {
  std::cout << "inside the process function:" << ptr.use_count() << "\n";
}

int main() {
  auto sp = std::make_shared<int>();
  process(sp);
  process(std::shared_ptr<int>(sp));
  return 0;
}
```

Both two outputs are 2, but why?

I think the second output should be 3.
Isn't std::shared_ptr(sp) a copy of sp, and isn't the parameter std::shared_ptr ptr in process function another copy of sp?

Comment: My gcc version is: gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Comment: And what standard version are you compiling against?

Comment: the second is just making an additional unnecessary temporary. Though that may be elided

Comment: standard version is C++14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 2 is very much correct.

`std::shared_ptr<int>(sp)` is a prvalue. Since C++17, it doesn't even materialize a temporary, rather being used to directly initialized `ptr`.

Prior to C++17, that temporary is still elgibile to be used as an argument to a shared_ptr's move constructor. `ptr` is move constructed from it, and basically takes over the temporarys ownership instead of incrementing the ref-count.

Comment: ok I got it, thx so much